# request MediaType "application/json" but received "text/html"

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, unmarshalling

I have the following get request to a RESTful web service:

```java
   List<ShoppingEntry> entries = client.target("http://localhost:8080/MMServer/webresources/shopping/getEntries")
                                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .get()
                                .readEntity(new GenericType<List<ShoppingEntry>>() {});
```

and the corresponding resource

```java
@GET
@Path("getEntries")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ShoppingEntry> getShoppingBundle() {

        List<ShoppingEntry> shoppingEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Shopping> shoppingList = super.findAll();
        ShoppingEntry entry;

        for (Shopping s: shoppingList) {

            entry = new ShoppingEntry();
            entry.setName(s.getIdperson().getFirstname());
            entry.setDate(s.getDate());
            entry.setAmount(s.getAmount());
            entry.setStore(s.getStore());

            shoppingEntries.add(entry);

        }

        return shoppingEntries;
    }
```

The problem: Sometimes the program runs without error and everything is alright. But most of the time i get the following exception:

org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html, type=interface java.util.List, genericType=java.util.List.

which says: "type=text/html" what should be the cause. How can this happen? 
My dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Try returning a Custom Response Class Object which contains the List<ShoppingEntry>

Comment: this could happen for many reason e.g exception not handled?  Application not deployed on local server, and it returns the default not found page. Try out printing the content of response if you get different media type to debug further